# Heaviside Step Function and its conventional definition

Tags: special-functions

Well known and conventional defintion of [Heaviside function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html) is

```
 H(x) = 0,   x < 0 
 H(x) = 1/2, x = 0
 H(x) = 1,   x > 0
```

Mathematica uses instead unconventional "unit step" for its $HeavisideTheta[x] $ function

```
 S(x) = 0,   x < 0 
 S(x) = 1,   x > 0
```

How to use in Mathematica proper Heaviside function with normal definiton $H(x)$?

Comment: Actually, `UnitStep` is a separate function, and the link you provided states that `HeavisideTheta` can be defined in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myHeaviside[x_] := Which[x < 0, 0, x == 0, 1/2, x > 0, 1]
```

Note that the derivative, computed as a limit, is properly a representation of a DiracDelta function (though its integral and higher derivatives might not be appropriately represented):

```
Limit[(myHeaviside[x + ε] - myHeaviside[x])/ε, ε -> 0]
```

$\begin{cases}
 \infty  & x=0 \\
 0 & \text{True}
\end{cases}$

Comment: What do you mean by ``the derivative is properly calculated''? The derivative should yield `DiracDelta`, I believe.

Answer (score 7):

As the link in the question states, you can get the desired definition as follows:

```
heaviside[x_] := 1/2 (1 + Sign[x])
```

Here is a test:

```
heaviside /@ {-1, 0, 1}
```

> `{0, 1/2, 1}`